# Can I run DeepLearning4J on an AMD GPU?

Tags: deeplearning4j

I think DeepLearning4j uses CUDA, which is a NVIDIA thing. I bought this computer for things like neural networks but now I'm disappointed that I have an AMD GPU. Is it somehow possible that I can run DeepLearning4J on AMD?

Answer (score 4):

It's actually not "deeplearning4j" you should be looking at.

Dl4j uses a tensor library which talks to the hardware called nd4j.

Nd4j has "backends" you can plugin. The available backends are various cpu architectures ranging from IBM's power to Android and x86.

GPU wise yes we only support cuda. It's not a simple binary answer like what you're describing.

In theory, we could add opencl at some point but then "which version of opencl"?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use dl4j with AMD GPU